# iPad Chrome has wrong height when open a page in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, ipad

**Ipad information**
Model Name: Ipad (9th generation)
Software version: 15.4.1

Chrome Information
Version: 121.0.6167.138

I saw a problem that $(window).height(); when I open a page in new tab (target="_blank").
I have two html page like that:

**Page01.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=Device-Width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="JS_CSS/JS/jquery.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script >
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var heightWin =  $(window).height()
            alert('Win height: ' + heightWin);
        });
    </script>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div style="width: 100%; border: solid 2px red;  box-sizing:border-box" class="my-element">
            <a href="https://nghiashare.w3spaces.com/Page02.html" target="_self"> WebForm2.aspx _self</a>
            <br />
            <br />
            <a href="https://nghiashare.w3spaces.com/Page02.html" target="_blank">WebForm2.aspx _blank</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click "WebForm2.aspx _self" link in Page01.html, Chrome alert heightWin is 965

When I click "WebForm2.aspx _blank" link in Page01.html, Chrome alert heightWin is 1060

The problem only happens on Chrome. If I use safari, there is no problem.

You can try to access my example online in the link
https://nghiashare.w3spaces.com/page01.html

Thank you very much for suggesting me the reason and solution for this problem.
Yours.
Nghia

Comment: Have you checked/compared all the settings on Safari and Chrome. It seems that in Chrome it may default to assuming full device height if _target is used.

Comment: @AHaworth Thank for your feedback. BUT I could not find any setting related to "full device height if _target is used." in chrome in Ios

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what size you want to read, the browser provides two values:

the first one returns the size of the window with frames,
the second one returns the internal size of the window with the content (viewport)

```
window.outerHeight
window.innerHeight
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your idea, but it is still giving me wrong height. <br> When I click "WebForm2.aspx _self" link in Page01.html, Chrome alert: win height: 965, inner height:965, outer height: 1080.  <br> When I click "WebForm2.aspx _blank" link in Page01.html, Chrome alert win height: 1060, inner height: 1060, outer height: 1080. Do you have any idea for this? is it a bug of chrome on Ios? Thank you for your support.